Rotate an array in-place
I'm trying to practice my Python on Leetcode.
The question is 189. Rotate Array.
Although it works correctly in other IDEs, It's still wrong in Leetcode. Here is my Code:
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        from collections import deque
        nums = deque(nums)
        for i in range(k):
            nums.appendleft(nums.pop())
        nums = list(nums)
        print(nums)

Still don't know. What's the issue on my code?

It tells you to modify nums in-place.

nums = deque(nums) After calling this line of code, nums no longer refers to the original input argument, so you are NOT modifying nums in-place as the instructions ask.

In future, please note that a question should be self-contained, as much as possible. Supplementary links are always welcome, but a question should be comprehensible even if all the links stop working.

list and deque create a different object it's not considered to be replacing in-place of list
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        k = k % len(nums)
        l,r = 0, len(nums) -1

        while l<r:
          nums[l],nums[r] = nums[r], nums[l]
          l,r = l+1, r-1

        l,r = 0, k-1
        while l<r:
          nums[l],nums[r] = nums[r], nums[l]
          l,r = l+1, r-1
        
        l, r = k , len(nums) -1
        while l<r:
          nums[l],nums[r] = nums[r], nums[l]
          l,r = l+1, r-1
        
        



list(nums) and deque(nums) would create a completely different list object so it's not considered to be replacing in-place of the list. I think you would have to use general assign value statement to the list at index i (ie nums[i] = <value>). Below code is one of the approach using recursive dfs with in-place list modification
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        
        k = k % len(nums)
        def traverse(nums, i, k, value, count, origin):
            next_i = (i + k) % len(nums)
            if next_i != origin and count < len(nums):
                count = traverse(nums, next_i, k, nums[i], count + 1, origin)
            nums[i] = value
            return count

        count = 0
        offset = 0
        while count < len(nums):
            count = traverse(nums, k + offset, k, nums[offset], count + 1, offset + k)
            offset += 1
    
        return nums


Your solution works, but not based on the requirement. It is simply not what the problem is about.
You need to not change the nums and perform all the operations in-place:
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        from collections import deque
        A = deque(nums[:])
        for i in range(k):
            A.appendleft(A.pop())
        nums[:] = list(A)


To "bypass" the requirements, you define A as a new variable and copy nums into A.

Then again, copy back A into nums using nums[:].

Note that, this is not what they asked, but to simply show you that you have solved the problem not based on the requirement though.



A much simple solution would be to use slicing as follows:
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int):
        l = len(nums)
        if k < 1 or l < 2 or k == l:
            return

        k %= l
        nums[:] = nums[-k:] + nums[:l - k]
        print(nums)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Solution().rotate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], k=3))
    print(Solution().rotate([-1, -100, 3, 99], k=2))


Prints
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 99, -1, -100]

It is dubious to say "it works OK" when it patently doesn't do what the Leetcode requirements ask for.


My submission is correct ...

It isn't.  Your code doesn't meet the requirements for this problem as other answers and comments have explained.

Although it works correctly in other IDEs ...

It doesn't.
The reason you think that it "works" is that your testing methodology is incorrect!
A proper test for your code would be something like this:
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Solution().rotate(test, k=3)
print(test)

That would show that your solution outputs something like this:
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

The first line comes from the print statement in your method.  (It should not be there.  A method shouldn't output stuff unless the requirements explicitly say that it should.)
The second line is from the print after returning to your test code ... and it shows that test has NOT been modified in place.
